# Reflection on mocked data in unit tests (Rhino)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have some code that selects a property using reflection. It works fine but I can't unit test it. Apparently, the mock that it creates does not have any properties.
Can anyone tell me how to get the property from a Mocked object using reflection? (Or explain why it would not be possible?)

```
var target = To.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Single(x => typeof(IRepository<T>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
    .GetValue(To) as IRepository<T>;
```

I'm using this for a copy class which allows to copy data for any entity type and expects a UnitOfWork that contains a IRepository where T is the type that you want to copy.

```
public class TableCopier<T> : ICopier where T : EntityBase
{
    public IUnitOfWork From { get; set; }
    public IUnitOfWork To { get; set; }

    public virtual int Copy(IProgressReporter progres = null)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            var target = To.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Single(x => typeof(IRepository<T>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
                .GetValue(To) as IRepository<T>;
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

The Unit of Work looks like this:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Parameter> ParameterRepository { get; }
    IRepository<Company> CompanyRepository { get; }
    IRepository<CompanyAccountancynumber> CompanyAccountancynumberRepository { get; }
    //...
```

And finally the unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void DefaultCopy()
    {
        // (removed some code)
        var to = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IUnitOfWork>();

        var target = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IRepository<CompanyDataset>>();
        to.Stub(x => x.CompanyDatasetRepository).Return(target);
        var inserted = new List<CompanyDataset>();
        target.Stub(x => x.BulkInsert(null))
            .IgnoreArguments()
            .WhenCalled(x => inserted.AddRange(x.Arguments[0] as IEnumerable<CompanyDataset>));

        //ACT
        var copier = new TableCopier<CompanyDataset>() as ICopier;
        copier.Copy(from, to, map, log, null, CancellationToken.None );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
The properties are available as explicit properties.
And to access these kind of properties you need the interface map.

This means I should change this:

```
var target = To.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Single(x => typeof(IRepository<T>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
    .GetValue(To) as IRepository<T>;
```

To this:

```
var target = To.GetType().GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InterfaceMethods
    .Single(x => (typeof(IRepository<T>).IsAssignableFrom(x.ReturnType)))
    .Invoke(To, null) as IRepository<T>;
```

My own implementations of IUnitOfWork used 'implicit' properties, so that explains why that worked and the unit test failed. Also using the map is generally better (/more correct) (-> no chance on problems if I would ever make another implementation of the interface with explicit props). So I suppose it was a good unit test :)

Regards